# Return false not working after form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, bootstrap-4

I'm submiting a contact form to my backend script with bootstrap form and ajax.

`return false` is not preventing my form from submiting again after ajax callback. This causes a new bootstrap form validation, displaying input errors messages.

I read some similar questions even with `event.preventDefault()` but it did not work.

**html**

```
    <body>

    <form id="contact-form" method="POST" class="needs-validation" onsubmit="return false" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="name">Nome</label>
         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" required />
         <div class="invalid-feedback">
             Please, type your name
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="email">Email</label>
         <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" required />
         <div class="invalid-feedback">
            Please, type your e-mail
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label for="subject">Assunto</label>
         <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="message">Mensagem</label>
          <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="3" required minlength="10"></textarea>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
             Leave your message
          </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn send-btn">Enviar</button>
      <div id="messages" class="show_messages"></div>
      <div id="error_messages" class="show_error"></div>
    </form>


 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>

(function () {
    'use strict';
     window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
        var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function (form) {
           form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
             if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
             }
           form.classList.add('was-validated');

           if (form.checkValidity() === true) {

              var name = $("input#name").val();
              var email = $("input#email").val();
              var subject = $("input#subject").val();
              var message = $("textarea#message").val();
              var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&subject=' + subject + '&message=' + message;
              var url = "./serverside/send-mail.php";

              $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: url,
                 data: dataString,
                 success: function (data) {

                 console.log(data);
                 var response = JSON.stringify(data);
                 console.log(response);

                 if (data == "\"E-mail sent\"") {

                 console.log("email sent after stringify");

                 $("#messages").addClass("messages")
                   .html("<img src='./img/check.png' alt='Check' /> Message sent!")
                   .hide().fadeIn(800, function () {
                       setTimeout(() => {
                          $("#messages").hide(500);
                       }, 3000);
                    });
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();

                 } else {
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    console.log("E-mail was not sent");

                    $("#error_messages").addClass("error_messages")
                     .html("<img src='./img/warning.png' alt='Warning' /> Ops! Error sending your message.")
                     .hide().fadeIn(800, function () {
                        setTimeout(() => {
                           $("#error_messages").hide(500);
                        }, 3000);
                     });
                                    }
               },
               error: function (e) {
                 console.log(e);
                 $("#error_messages").addClass("error_messages")
                  .html("<img src='./img/warning.png' alt='Warning' /> Ops! Error sending your message.")
                  .hide().fadeIn(800, function () {
                     setTimeout(() => {
                       $("#error_messages").hide(500);
                     }, 3000);
                  });
                 }
            });
            return false;
         }

     }, false);
   });
 }, false);
})();
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: you should always fire the `preventDefault`, not only if `checkValidity` is false.

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky yep. I did it now removing it from the form and adding `event.preventDefault();` after `if (form.checkValidity() === true) {...` line but it didn't work yet.

Comment: Your code looks messy. Why not just go full jQuery?

Comment: `if (form.checkValidity() === true)` can just be: `if (form.checkValidity())` because `checkValidity()` returns a Boolean. And, you can leave off the `false` parameter of your `.addEventListener()` calls because `false` is the default value for that argument.

Comment: @ScottMarcus okay, thanks. But it does not solve the issue.

Comment: I know. It was just an FYI. The cleaner your code is, the easier it is to diagnose and get working.

Comment: It's not complicated. I just added messages into divs to display to the user if email was sent or not. Just like here https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tests I finally found the solution. After `reset()` the form I should remove the class `was-validated`.

```
if (data == "\"E-mail sent\"") {

   console.log("email sent after stringify");

   $("#messages").addClass("messages")
   .html("<img src='./img/check.png' alt='Check' /> Message sent!")
   .hide().fadeIn(800, function () {
        setTimeout(() => {
          $("#messages").hide(500);
        }, 3000);
    });

    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
    form.classList.remove('was-validated');

} else {

...
```

Maybe it is a workaround but it worked.